# How to make the first menu link look as if it is hovered until hovering another link

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a menu which changes the links background image on hover and also replaces for each link a center image in the "frame" of that menu.
What I need to do is make the first link of the menu show as if it is hovered all the time and its center image show as well but it should be turned off once hovering one of the other menu links.
Any ideas?

Comment: provide some code or fiddle link

Comment: Please post the code what you have so far?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried till now.

Comment: Sorry the link to the menu:
http://www.israelijewel.com/1.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you can't control a parent element with only css, so you have to do some trick:

For example, if you have a multi-level menu, you can retain style applied to a father element simply writing something like this:

```
ul li:hover li
{
   ...
}
```

In this way, assuming a mouse hover on a nested LI, will apply style also to father one, for example main list-item in main bar.

If tou have not a multi-level menu, you can anyway declare it in html, and stylize everything to appear as all equal level links, just to reach your objective ;-)

**UPDATE AFTER COMMENTS**
Here the jquery Code:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

   $('.home-gallery a').hover(
     function() {
       $('.mofet-link').removeClass( "active" );
       $('.mofet-link img').removeClass( "active_img" );
     }, 
     function() 
     {
       $('.mofet-link').addClass( "active" );
       $('.mofet-link img').addClass( "active_img" );
     });
});
```

you must also modify your css, adding some rules:

```
.active_img, .mofet-link:hover img {
    display: block !important;
    max-height: 250px !important;
    max-width: none;
    right: 220px;
    top: 20px;
}


.active, .mofet-link:hover {
    background-image: url("http://www.israelijewel.com/websites/mishne-torah/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen-child/images/gallery/mofet-button.jpg");
    background-position: right 4px top 6px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

And, in order to correctly run jQuery, put it in HEAD section of the page. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The menu is not a multi-level menu, there is one link to each category, you can see in the following link:
http://www.israelijewel.com/1.html

Comment: You can't do it with pure css with actual structure of html. If you want to mantain actual html, you should use JQuery in order to add/remove a specific class on first menu item, when hovering on another one.

Alternatively, if you don't want to use Jquery, you should change your html code, putting all other links, inside first LI, making your menu (structurally) a multi-level menu. Then you can add CSS in order to display them like now, but backstage is a nested menu. Tt's not a clean html code.... but it will work, if you don't want use jQuery.

Comment: I don'y mind using Jquery but I don't know how to...
Is there some thing similar that you can direct me to so that I'll learn how to do it? Or a sample code from your sleeve?
Thanks!

Comment: Okay, I added all the above code int he page, but it didn't seem to do anything.
Perhaps I didn't put the Jquery code in the right place? I did try to put it in the Head and also in the Body section, and then in both but nothing...
Where exactly should the Jquery code go?

Comment: It miss the READY() clause. ;-) Please, look at code

Comment: This is now very very close to what I need!
A small addition at the top of the Jquery fixed it to be exactly what I need:
 window.onload=
   (function() 
  {
    $('.mofet-link').addClass( "active" );
    $('.mofet-link img').addClass( "active_img" );
  });
Now on page load the first menu item is shown as if it is chosen until hovering the other menu items which is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Instead of window.onload, is better ready() method of jQuery. The main difference is that functions included in Ready() clause will fire after DOM loading, but before images loading (instead of window.onload that it will fire only after all elements are loaded).

Comment: Did what you suggest and it works perfect!
Now I encounter another problem, the same page that has this menu also has another element that is using Jquery 1.9.0 min and if I have the latest Jquery loading in the head with 1.9.0 the other element that is using 1.9.0 is not functioning correctly.
This can be seen on the following link:
http://www.israelijewel.com/websites/mishne-torah/

Any ideas? Should I list a new question?

Comment: Yes... better new question, because is a separated topic. Anyway, is strange because I wrote a very simple code that should work with every jQuery version.... Try 1.11 instead of 2.1... because there are some breaking points between two versions :-)

Comment: I did it 1.11.0 and both are working fine! If you think that for other people looking for answers it would be important I will make a new question any way and will answer it but I am not sure its necessary...
Thanks again for the fast and good solutions

Answer (score 0):

The idea: wrap all buttons inside a new div, when you hover over that div remove the style of the first button UNLESS you are hovering the first button, then just style each button as you want on hover

html:

```
<div class='home_gallery'>
  <div id='buttons'>
    <a class='mofet-link' href='mofet'><img....></a>
    <!-- the rest of the a tags -->
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.mofet-link {
  //set the state you want initially, like when the mose hover over it
}
#buttons:hover .mofet-link {
  //set the state as NOT hovered
}
.mofet-link:hover {
  //set the state as hovered
}
```

Now, the default value would be the one given by the rule .mofet-link (hovered), when you hover over any button, the css will be the one at #buttons:hover .mofet-link (unhovered), unless you are hovering mofet-link, then the rules applied will be .mofet-link:hover (hovered)

You can play with the order a little or use something like:

```
.mofet-link:hover {
  background: your_background !important;
}
```

or write a more precise selector if you have some other css overriding what you want with more priority.

Hope that helps.